# "This site can't be reached" error when attempting to open Jupyter Notebook in AWS Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I attempt to open Jupyter Notebook from my AWS instance, I get the error:

```
This site can’t be reachedCheck if there is a typo in ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx.ec2.internal.
If spelling is correct, try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

I created a `mycert.pem` after pip3 installing Jupyter Notebook configured my jupyter_notebook_config.py like so:

```
c = get_config()

# Notebook config this is where you saved your pem cert
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/home/ec2-user/certs/mycert.pem'

# Run on all IP addresses of your instance
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
# Don't open browser by default
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
# Fix port to 8888
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888

# Configuration file for jupyter-notebook.
```

I've also adjusted the security groups for the instance and opened ports 80 and 443. Was there anything that I missed?

Comment: You are accessing the jupyter from the instance itself, or from outside of it? For example, from home/work computer?

Comment: I'm looking to access it from my instance